# How to change button color in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have posts displayed and I want the button to like a post to be red if the user has not liked the post yet, and yellow if the user has liked it. Now all buttons are red, even though I liked some of the posts. You can have a look at the code and see where the error is.

```php
public function colors()
{
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $like = $this->data['like'];
    $sql = $this->database->connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM user JOIN post ON user.id = post.user_id JOIN post_like ON post.id = post_like.post_id where post.user_id = :user_id and post_id = :post_id group by post.id DESC");
    $sql->bindParam(':user_id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->bindParam(':post_id', $like, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->execute();

    if ($sql->rowCount()) {
        return "yellow";
    } else
        return "red";
}
```

```php
<form action='' method='post' id="myForm">
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-12 col-xl-12 d-flex justify-content-between'>
            <button class='button2' name='dodaj_like' style="background-color: <?php echo $color ?>">
                <i class='fas fa-heart'></i>
                <input type='hidden' name='like' value="" onclick="myFunction()"/>
                <span id="laiki"><?php echo $user['likes']?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, where you actually check which number rowcount possses

```
$status = $sql->execute();
if (($status) && ($sql->rowCount() > 0)) {
    return "yellow"; 
} else {
        return "red";
}
```

Comment: That change nothing.

Comment: then the rowcount is 0 or the query has an error echo status and rowconut

Comment: Every button is red, but some posts I like , so button should be yellow. In my opinion problem is with $variable like.

Comment: have you chekc yor query with the echod varaböes $id and $like

Comment: Yes, I check it

Comment: now all buttons are yellow, even if I didn't like the post, but when I press the button of the post I didn't like, it displays all buttons in red.

Comment: it ist ill hard to guess what the result of your query are, besides a SELECT * seems unnece3ssary as A SELECT 1 would do the same, you shpuld take a step back and see if the query can detect the likes or not likes of every person, because as you don't add information on every button

Comment: `ELECT * FROM user JOIN post ON user.id = post.user_id JOIN post_like ON post.id = post_like.post_id where post.user_id = :user_id and post_id = :post_id group by post.id DESC` This query check if person like or not post.

Comment: Yes read your query already, but that only works if `$this->data['like'];` changes with every button, what it doesn't do